# Doctrine schema update or Doctrine migrations

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, database-schema

What are the practical advantages of Doctrine Migrations over just running a schema update?

**Safety?**

The `orm:schema-tool:update` command (`doctrine:schema:update` in Symfony) warns

> This operation should not be executed in a production environment.

but why is this? Sure, it can delete data but so can a migration.

**Flexibility?**

I thought I could tailor my migrations to add stuff like column defaults but this often doesn't work as Doctrine will notice the discrepancy between the schema and the code on the next diff and stomp over your changes.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

When you are using the `schema-tool`, no history of database modification is kept, and in a production/staging environment this is a big downside.

Let's assume you have a complicated database structure in a live project. And in the next changeset you have to alter the database somehow. For example, your users' contact phones need to be stored in a different format, not a `VARCHAR`, but three `SMALLINT` columns for country code, area code and the phone number.

Well, that's not so hard to figure out a query that would fetch the current data, separate it into three values and insert them back. That's when migrations come into play: you can create your new fields, then do the transforms and finally drop the field that was holding the data before.

And even more! You can even describe the backwards process (the `down` migration), when you need to undo the changes introduced in your migration. Let's assume that someone somewhere relied heavily on the format of the `VARCHAR` field, and now that you've changed the structure, his piece of code is not working as expected. So, you run `migration:down`, and everything gets reverted. In this specific case you'd just bring back the old `VARCHAR` column and concatenate the values back, and then drop the fields.

Doctrine's migration tool basically does most of the work for you. When you diff your schema, it generates all the necessary `up`'s and `down`'s, so only thing you'll have to do is handle the data that could be damaged when the migration is applied.

Also, migrations are something that gives other developers on your team knowledge on when it's time to update their schemas. With just the `schema-tool`, your teammates would have to run `doctrine:schema:update` each and every time they pull, `cause they wouldn't know if the schema has really changed.

When using migrations, you always see that there are some updates in the migrations folder, which means you need to update your schema.

Comment: Very helpful answer. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation

Comment: I would also add that Doctrine Migrations allows you to have hard-coded prod data, such as categories or a first admin user.

Without Migrations, you would have to use Doctrine Fixtures for that, which should be left to dev and testing environments.

Comment: That would not be really correct, since adding data via migrations could break in-app invariants and rules

Answer (score 3):

I think that you indeed nailed it on Safety. With Migrations you can go back to another state of the table (just like you can do in Git version control). With the schema update command you can only UPDATE the tables. There is no log kept for going back in case of a failure with already saved data in those tables. I don't know exactly, but doesn't a migration also saves the data of the corresponding table that's being updated? That would be essential in my opinion, otherwise there is no big reason to use them.

So yes, I personally think that the main reason for using migrations in a production environment is safety and maybe a bit of flexibility. Safety would be the winner here I think :)

Hope this helps.

edit: Here is another answer with references to the Symfony docs: [Is it safe to use doctrine2 migrations in production environment with symfony2 and php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11406689/is-it-safe-to-use-doctrine2-migrations-in-production-environment-with-symfony2-a)

Answer (score 0):

You also cant perform large updates with plain doctrine migration. Like try to update index on 30 mln users database. As it will a lot of time while you app will not be accessible.